# Why does it seem that g++ is mixing up data types?

Tags: c++, constructor, compiler-errors, g++, type-conversion

I am currently making a big integer library for my college assignment.
I am experiencing a problem with the following code:

```
MyInteger::MyInteger(){ //default
    //some code
}
MyInteger::MyInteger(char *s){ //construct from string
    //some code
}
MyInteger::MyInteger(MyInteger &otherInt){ //copy constructor
    //some code
}
MyInteger MyInteger::parse(char *s){ //parse string and create new object
    return MyInteger(s);
}
```

I get the following error about the parse function:

```
MyInteger.cpp: In static member function ‘static MyInteger MyInteger::parse(char*)’:
MyInteger.cpp:34:20: error: no matching function for call to ‘MyInteger::MyInteger(MyInteger)’
  return MyInteger(s);
                    ^
MyInteger.cpp:34:20: note: candidates are:
MyInteger.cpp:23:1: note: MyInteger::MyInteger(MyInteger&)
 MyInteger::MyInteger(MyInteger &otherInt){ //copy constructor
 ^
MyInteger.cpp:23:1: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘MyInteger’ to ‘MyInteger&’
MyInteger.cpp:10:1: note: MyInteger::MyInteger(char*)
 MyInteger::MyInteger(char *s){ //construct from string
 ^
MyInteger.cpp:10:1: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘MyInteger’ to ‘char*’
MyInteger.cpp:4:1: note: MyInteger::MyInteger()
 MyInteger::MyInteger(){ //set string to 0
 ^
MyInteger.cpp:4:1: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
```

Shouldn't it be using the 2nd constructor?
Either it is confusing the string with a MyInteger, or the string is being converted to a MyInteger somehow and then the compiler is trying to convert it again using the 3 candidates that it has listed. A similar error is occuring with the overloaded + operator.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: On a side note -- if those functions do not modify the buffer, pass the buffer as `const char *`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the `MyInteger(s)` that's the problem. It constructs that temporary object. It's the attempt to return this temporary object that is the problem. You are returning by value, which means that a copy needs to be made, yet your copy constructor takes a `MyInteger&`, which is unable to bind to temporary objects (rvalues). Your copy constructor should have parameter of type `const MyInteger&` instead, which will allow it to do so.

Comment: You can also introduce the default move-constructor: `MyInteger(MyInteger&&) = default;`

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not know that the const made such a difference, I thought it was just there to prevent accidental modification. I do not have enough reputation to upvote your answer, sorry.